# HTML/CSS - Line numbers that cannot be selected

Tags: html, css

I want to display some code in a block, and include line numbers. How can I get line numbers showing, that can't be selected, that does not rely on Javascript?

Pastebin.com appears to be able to do this, but I can't quite figure out how. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I rather assumed that pastebin used JavaScript...though on pastebin each line of the code is wrapped in an `li` element, this could be server-, or client-, side. But, either way, it's definitely *not* 'just html and css.'

Comment: Why not use Firebug or something like that to inspect the html/css on a pastebin page you like and see what they are doing.

Comment: Do you want them to not be selectable at all or just that you can select the code without the numbers?

Comment: @DavidThomas It is 'just html and css'. I specifically disabled Javascript entirely to test.

Comment: @CliffRibaudo I did look, I didn't realize what was going on, but below two people answered already. Thanks!

Comment: If it was 'just html and css' why would the code be wrapped in `ol` and `li` elements once the code's displayed/posted/published (whatever)? There's something server-side happening to enable that display. As noted in my previous comment.

Comment: @DavidThomas You're nitpicking. I was referring to the actual page design, not serverside scripting, and that should be pretty apparent considering the tags are "HTML" and "CSS". Obviously Pastebin is dynamic, but that's irrelevant to the question I asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pastebin solves this by adding every line of the contents as a LI element in an ordered list.

```
<ol>
  <li>public void foo() {</li>
  <li>  System.out.println("bar");</li>
  <li>}</li>
</ol>
```

The numbers from an such a list doesn't get copied when selecting:

1. public void foo() {
2. System.out.println("bar");
3. }

The rest is styling using css.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of pastebin.com, they simply use an ordered list in HTML, which produces a numbered list of lines. YOu can't select the list item numbers or bullets in HTML…

Answer (score 0):

It's just simple `ol > li` (every line is an ordered list-item).